# How to set css of dataTable after reload?

Tags: datatables

There is a `dataTable` :

```
<table id="list_details_livraison" class="striped cell-hovered border bordered" data-searching="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.article');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.lot');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.qtelivrer');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.pu');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.taxe');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.remise');?></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;"><?php echo _getText('detaillivraison.entete.prixtotal');?></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

$(document).ready(function(){
     var list_details_livraison = $('#list_details_livraison').DataTable({
           ...
           "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                                    $(this).css("table-layout","fixed");
                                }
        });
```

Then I filter the dataTable by selecting a value from a select element :

```
$('#cacher').on("change", function() {
     var ddeb = convertDateFormat3($("#date_deb_").val());
     var dfin = convertDateFormat3($("#date_fin_").val());
     list_details_livraison.ajax.url("<?php echo RP_SSP; ?>server_processing_livraisons_frnsr.php?ddeb="+ddeb+"&dfin="+dfin+"&type="+$("#h_filtre_type_livraison").val()+"&valider="+$("#h_filtre_etre_valider").val()).load();
});
```

At runtime the dataTable's columns are not autowidth after I make the filter ; I tried using `list_details_livraison.css("table-layout","fixed");` but I got a console error ! So how to reapply the `table-layout` `fixed` css at this moment ?

Comment: You probably need to use [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) as `initComplete` only runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment converted into an answer at the request of the OP.

[initComplete()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) will only run once per table creation, so won't be called after subsequent paging, filtering etc.  For this you need [drawCallback()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) which gets called after every `draw`.

You just need to change:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
```

to

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
```